# asp.net mvc - How to tell child action to ignore layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I'm using `@Html.Action()` to render a child action within my view.

The `_ViewStart.cshtml` file specifies that all views should use a particular layout like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Problem is, that layout is getting applied to my child action too, so the final page ends up with two headers and two footers. How do I prevent this?

Comment: That should be impossible. How are you inserting the child action into your page? `@Html.RenderAction` with a `return PartialView()`?

Comment: The parent controller just has `@Html.Action("[Name of action]", "[Name of controller]", Model);`.

Comment: I was getting a StackOverflowException when I called a child action because I was calling the child action from my main _Layout.cshtml file, and it was trying to include another _Layout.cshtml which included my child action again... this eventually crashed the w3wp.exe process. The accepted answer - to return a PartialView from my child action - fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

2 possibilities:

1. `return PartialView()` from the corresponding controller action instead of a `return View()`
2. Blank out the layout in the view itself

   ```
   @{
       Layout = null;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is basically what I suspect is happening. Your action has a `return View` call instead of `return PartialView` OP

Comment: And you are quite right. I didn't know I needed to call `PartialView()`. Thanks!

Comment: Can't mark you correct for another 8 minutes. Otherwise the world would collapse.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you want to use `ChildActionOnly` and don't want to pass the model from view then you can not user PartialView.

If it is so, you need to remove the layout manually

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
```

Comment: just a small note: `Layout ="";` is not the same as `Layout = null;` I tried both and only the latter worked.